# Clarification about this step taken in this proof of differentiation

Tags: derivatives

I was looking at proofs of the differentiation of exponentiation and I'm confused about the last step of this part of the proof:

$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ =
$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{x^n-x_0^n}{x-x_0}$ = $\lim_{x \to x_0}(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2} \cdot x_0+x^{n-3} \cdot x_0^2+...+x^2 \cdot x_0^{n-3}+x \cdot x_0^{n-2}+x_0^{n-1})$

The proof continues but I'm not sure what exactly the last step has been. If somebody could explain what has been done I would be really thankful.

Comment: Factorise $x^n-x_0^n$ into $(x-x_0)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}x_0+...)$

Comment: I already thought about doing it this way, but I was not quite sure how to divide $x^n-x_0^n$ by $x-x_0$.

I guess you could say I had trouble calculating it more than understanding what was done, I was confusing in my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly we can write the expression with a sigma sign.

$$S_n=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2} \cdot x_0+x^{n-3} \cdot x_0^2+...+x^2 \cdot x_0^{n-3}+x \cdot x_0^{n-2}+x_0^{n-1})=\frac1{x_0}x^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^i$$

We have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n q^i$ is $q\cdot \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$. This is the partial sum of a geometric series.

For $q=\frac{x_0}{x}$ we obtain

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^i=\frac{x_0}{x}\cdot \frac{\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^n-1}{\frac{x_0}{x}-1}=x_0\cdot \frac{\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^n-1}{x_0-x}$$

Expanding the fraction by $x^n$

$\large{x_0\cdot \frac{x_0^n-x^n}{x_0-x}\cdot \frac1{x^n}}$

Finally we have to regard the factor $\frac1{x_0}x^n$

$$S_n=x_0\cdot \frac{x_0^n-x^n}{x_0-x}\cdot \frac1{x^n}\cdot \frac1{x_0}x^n=\frac{x_0^n-x^n}{x_0-x}=\frac{x^n-x_0^n}{x-x_0}$$

If you want to do it the other way round just make a polynomial division. I started by calculating the first two summands.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helps to understand what you are doing!

However, I am still interested how the proof does it the other way?

It starts off with $\frac{x^n-x_0^n}{x-x_0}$
My problem seems to be how to calculate the division.

Comment: Just go the reverse way.

Comment: Maybe I'm just too stupid, but I don't think that's the way that was used in the original proof. Still thank you for the answer, it helps my general understanding of calculating stuff.

Comment: @NotSureHowToDoStuff I´ve  made an edit.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I found my mistake in my polynomial division. I wasn't always trying to eliminate the highest potency.

Comment: You´re welcome. Nice to that you´ve managed it.